# mysql str_to_date incorrect datetime value issue

Tags: mysql

I can't work out why mysql is not liking my datetime value?

```
mysql> select  STR_TO_DATE('2017-10-06T00:00:00', '%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%i:%%s');
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2017-10-06T00:00:00', '%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%i:%%s') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings
    -> ;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                  |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '2017-10-06T00:00:00' for function str_to_date |
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '2017-10-06T00:00:00' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Why the double `%`? I think you only need one per param (i.e. `"%Y-%m-%dT...etc."`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(
  '2017-10-06T00:00:00',
  '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s'
);
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bG3WJwevrJ2GsfWWbjUE9w/0).

Comment: Excellent thanks for your answer. That works. The issue i'm having though is i am working with someone else's code and it they have wrapped a SQL statement in Heredoc Syntax then they are replacing a certain part with sprintf() so that is trying to replace the seconds format (%s). I guess this is why they have used %%s for the seconds. Do you know if the double percent can only be used on certain versions of mysql?

Comment: @SamBremner: According to the documentation, `%%` = `A literal % character`, see [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: Yea i noticed that, i even looked at the mysql manual going back to version 4 and its the same. With that being the case i cant see how this code ever worked but never mind i will change it to use just one %.